# Sublime Text 3 Api for close a view?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there any sublime text 3 api for closing a view??? closing a tab???

Yes the above line describes completely my problem. But it seems do not meet the requirement of this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I make any difference between a view and a tab.

Anyhow, to close a view: view.close()
To close a window: win.run_command('close_window')

If you want to close a window having modified buffers, you can discard these changes by scratching the view, as follow:

```
for win in sublime.windows():
    for view in win.views():
        view.set_scratch(True)
    win.run_command('close_window')
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: In Sublime 2, I get the message, `AttributeError: 'View' object has no attribute 'close'`.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this works in Sublime 2 for closing the currently active view in a window:

```
view.window().run_command('close_file')
```

It probably works in Sublime 3. I guessed the name of the command just by seeing that "Close Window" (the name of the command in the other answer) and "Close File" were options under the File menu.

Doing something like `view.window().open_file(view.file_name())` or `view.window().focus_view(view)` before the above will probably let you close an arbitrary file instead of just the one that's active before the command is executed.